# Reshape data for histograms (multhist)

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram, reshape

I want to convert my data to plot different histograms next to each other (probably with `multhist`).
My data now looks like:

```
    Code Pt
     0   5
     0   0
     0   2 
     1   0
     1   3
     1   1
    30   0
    30   6
    30   2
```

and so on. 
Each code number stands for one species and I would like to plot histograms of Pt for each species (code number) next to each other.
Therefore, I want the data to be reshaped like:

```
    Code Pt
     0   5
     0   5
     0   5
     0   5
     0   5
     0   0
     0   2
     0   2
     1   0
     1   3
     1   3
     1   3
```

and so on.

I have already tried

```
    hp<-read.table("C:/Users/file.csv", header=T, sep=";")
    hp$Code<-as.factor(hp$Code)
    with(hp,data.frame(
    Code=rep(Code,Pt),Ptdet=rep(Pt,Code)))
```

But I get the error: arguments imply differing number of rows. Maybe this is due to the "0" in my data frame?
Probably it is an easy thing, nevertheless I am struggeling and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,rep(Pt, max(Pt,1)),by=.(Code, Pt)][,.(Code, Pt)]

#    Code Pt
# 1:    0  5
# 2:    0  5
# 3:    0  5
# 4:    0  5
# 5:    0  5
# 6:    0  0
# 7:    0  2
# 8:    0  2
# 9:    1  0
#10:    1  3
#11:    1  3
#12:    1  3
#13:    1  1
#14:   30  0
#15:   30  6
#16:   30  6
#17:   30  6
#18:   30  6
#19:   30  6
#20:   30  6
#21:   30  2
#22:   30  2
```

Comment: That works! But with `multhist` I have to change the table so that I have 0,1 and 30 as columns, I guess. Do you know a simple solution to that?

Comment: sorry? I do not get it. You want to transpose this data.table?

Comment: not in the typical sense: I want 3 columns c(0,1,30) and my values of the Pt-column then in the according columns of the three columns c(0,1,30)

Comment: slightly simpler: `dt[, .(Pt = rep(Pt, pmax(1L,Pt))), by=Code]`